# Javascript closure doesn&#39;t recognize global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

Tried to run some end to end test on UI with testcafe. The following script is supposed to take an input from user and evaluate it at the run time to help with developing new test scripts.
However, it doesn't recognize `Selector`.

For example

```
>> console.log("hi")
hi
>> t.click(Selector('button').withText('Google Search'))
 ✖ test 1

   1) ReferenceError: Selector is not defined

      Browser: Chrome 80.0.3987.162 / macOS 10.15.4

         12 |let x = "";
         13 |
         14 |test('test 1', async (t) => {
         15 |    while (1) {
         16 |      x = await getInput();
       > 17 |      eval(x)
         18 |   }
         19 |})
         20 |
         21 |async function getInput() {
         22 |  return new Promise(
```

Any idea why?  Thanks!!

Here is the code

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';
import readline from "readline";

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

fixture`test page`
  .page(`https://www.google.com`)

let x = "";

test('test 1', async (t) => {
    while (1) {
      x = await getInput();
      eval(x)
    }
})

async function getInput() {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      rl.question(">> ", function (txt) {
        resolve(txt)
      })
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe uses Babel that can transform the `import` statement. I suggest you use `require` for this case. The following line should make your test work:

`const Selector = require('testcafe').Selector;`